# DELETE year, month, day, time, temp, count(*) FROM Weather GROUP BY year, month, day, time, temp having COUNT(*) >1;

Tags: duplicates

I need help changing syntax to delete duplicates in my data. I have tried the following query:

```
DELETE year, month, day, time, temp, COUNT(*)
FROM Weather
GROUP BY year, month, day, time, temp
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: Can you show the full create table statement for `Weather`?